# Mailchimp : Filtering data returned form a cURL request

Tags: json, curl, mailchimp

I'm trying to make curl request to mailchimp in order to retrieve members informations. According to the doc, a special parameters name `fields` can be passed to the query in order to filter the result to the desired fields. See straight from the doc :

> Query string parameters :
>
> fields
>
> Type: Array
>   Title: Fields
>   Read only: false
>
> A comma-separated list of fields to return. Reference parameters of
>   sub-objects with dot notation.

The following data structure is returned on a sucessfull request :

```
{"members":[{"id":"106b60f0cdc8db34b7aae820d345ebd8","email_address":"blabla@freddiesjokes.com"
,"unique_email_id":"88e38b5109","email_type":"html","status":"subscribed",
"merge_fields":{"FNAME":"","LNAME":""} .... ]}
```

As you can see the email_address field is present. Therefore the following request always return an `{}` to me

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/744415ffa6/members?fields=email_adress' \
--user 'smth:apikey' \
--include
```

Is there something wrong with the request ? Without the fields parameters it correctly fetch the data. I see it's supposed to be an array, which, for me, means i could chain the fields parameters such as `fields=blabla&fields=john&fields=doe` do i stand correct on this ?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Look at: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/ which suggests you need to separate different fields with a comma and use the `lists.` prefix as in:

```
curl https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists?fields=lists.email_adress'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Somehow this didn't get the trick. Im able to filter those fields after the HTTP GET request, by parsing the json returned from MC. Therefore when i call this `https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/list_id/members?fields=lists.name,lists.id` i got a correct 200 response but an empty object ( list_id is replaced by the correct values ) which i dont get. Everything seems good on the mailchimp side since im able to query every of my user and filter them, however i dont seem to be able to filter those fields via MC integration

Comment: `lists.id` is a field of an audience. To filter `members` endpoint, use `members.name,members.id`.